# Not accepting other option entered by user

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I have to do the caesar cipher in C. Encryption and decrytion depending on the key and password (4 characters maximun) plus shifting direction, all three are given by the user.
In my code it only takes left, and when I enter right it re-asks for the direction again. I don't know what's wrong.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char pass[4];
char shiftdirection[6];
char left[6] = "left";
char right[6] = "right";
char ch;
int i, key;

void readline (){ //cette fonction prend de l'utilisateur le password et la clé
    do{
    printf("Please enter the pass, max 4 characters: \n");
    gets(pass);
    }while((strlen(pass)>4) || (strlen(pass)<4)); //get the password from th
    printf("Please enter the key: \n");
    scanf("%d",&key);
}

//cette fonction utilisée pour chiffrer
void encrypt(){
    printf("Enter the direction: \n");
    scanf("%s", &shiftdirection);
    while ((strcmp(shiftdirection,left)==1) || (strcmp(shiftdirection,right)==1)) { // demander de l'utilisateur la direction de décalage

        printf("Enter the direction: \n");
        scanf("%s", &shiftdirection);
    }
    if(strcmp(shiftdirection,left)==0){ // si l'utilisateur a écrit left, le programme commence le chiffrage avec un décalage à gauche
    for( i = 0; pass[i] != '\0'; i++){
        ch = pass[i];
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            ch = (char) (ch + key);
            if(ch > 'z'){
                ch = (char) (ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
            }
            pass[i] = ch;
        }
        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            ch = (char) (ch + key);
            if(ch > 'Z'){
                ch = (char) (ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
                }
            pass[i] = ch;
            }
        }
    }
   else if(strcmp(shiftdirection,right)==0){ // si l'utilisateur a écrit left, le programme commence le chiffrage avec un décalage à gauche
        for( i = strlen(pass) - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            ch = pass[i];
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = (char) (ch + key);
                if(ch > 'z'){
                    ch = (char) (ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
                }
                pass[i] = ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = (char) (ch + key);
                if(ch > 'Z'){
                    ch = (char) (ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
                }
                pass[i] = ch;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Encrypted Password is %s", pass); // le password chiffré
}

//cette fonction utilisée pour déchiffrer
void decrypt(){
    for(i = 0 ; pass[i] != '\0' ; ++i){
        ch = pass[i];
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            ch = (char) (ch - key);
            if(ch < 'a') {
                ch = (char) (ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1);
            }
            pass[i] = ch;
        } else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            ch = (char) (ch - key);
            if(ch < 'A'){
                ch = (char) (ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1);
            }
            pass[i] = ch;
        }
    }
    printf("\nDecrypted Password is %s", pass); //le password déchiffré
}
//main
int main() {
    readline();
    encrypt();
    decrypt();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: INPUT AND OUTPUT]

Comment: `char pass[4]; gets(pass);
    }while((strlen(pass)>4) || (strlen(pass)<4));` the test is useless, and if you enter 4 chars, you have already overflowed your buffer because you forgot the line termination char. Don't use `gets` BTW

Comment: Not only is `gets(pass);` an obsolete function, but `char pass[4];` is not long enough to hold the 4 characters plus a `nul` string terminator (dup of Jean-François).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As people in the comments mentioned you have to change the `char pass[4] -> char pass[5]` to consider the `\0` or `\n` from pressing return.
2. Do not use `gets`. Use `fgets` instead cause `gets` is unsafe and not part of C anymore
3. Use `getchar()` to capture leftover `\0` by the press of return
4. change `scanf` to `scanf_s` for more secure
5. Your `while ((strcmp(shiftdirection,left)==1) || (strcmp(shiftdirection,right)==1))` checks if one of the conditions isn't true then enters. You need to check if both conditions are not true so you need `&&` instead of `||`

I have played with your code a little bit and came up with the following.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char pass[5];
char shiftdirection[6];
char left[6] = "left";
char right[6] = "right";
char ch;
int i, key;

void readline (){ //cette fonction prend de l'utilisateur le password et la clé
    do{
    printf("Please enter the pass, max 4 characters: \n");
    fgets(pass, sizeof pass, stdin);
    }while((strlen(pass)>4) || (strlen(pass)<4)); //get the password from th
    printf("Please enter the key: \n");
    scanf_s("%d",&key);
    getchar();
}

//cette fonction utilisée pour chiffrer
void encrypt(){
    printf("Enter the direction: \n");
    fgets(shiftdirection, sizeof shiftdirection, stdin);
    shiftdirection[strcspn(shiftdirection, "\n\r")] = 0;
    while ((strcmp(shiftdirection,left)==1) && (strcmp(shiftdirection,right)==1)) { // demander de l'utilisateur la direction de décalage

        printf("Enter the direction: \n");
        fgets(shiftdirection, sizeof shiftdirection, stdin);
        shiftdirection[strcspn(shiftdirection, "\n\r")] = 0;
    }
    if(strcmp(shiftdirection,left)==0){ // si l'utilisateur a écrit left, le programme commence le chiffrage avec un décalage à gauche
    for( i = 0; pass[i] != '\0'; i++){
        ch = pass[i];
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            ch = (char) (ch + key);
            if(ch > 'z'){
                ch = (char) (ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
            }
            pass[i] = ch;
        }
        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            ch = (char) (ch + key);
            if(ch > 'Z'){
                ch = (char) (ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
                }
            pass[i] = ch;
            }
        }
    }
   else if(strcmp(shiftdirection,right)==0){ // si l'utilisateur a écrit left, le programme commence le chiffrage avec un décalage à gauche
        for( i = strlen(pass) - 1; i >= 0; --i){
            ch =pass[i];
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = (char) (ch + key);
                if(ch > 'z'){
                    ch = (char) (ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1);
                }
                pass[i] = ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = (char) (ch + key);
                if(ch > 'Z'){
                    ch = (char) (ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1);
                }
                pass[i] = ch;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Encrypted Password is %s", pass); // le password chiffré
}

//cette fonction utilisée pour déchiffrer
void decrypt(){
    for(i = 0 ; pass[i] != '\0' ; ++i){
        ch = pass[i];
        if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            ch = (char) (ch - key);
            if(ch < 'a') {
                ch = (char) (ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1);
            }
            pass[i] = ch;
        } else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
            ch = (char) (ch - key);
            if(ch < 'A'){
                ch = (char) (ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1);
            }
            pass[i] = ch;
        }
    }
    printf("\nDecrypted Password is %s", pass); //le password déchiffré
}
//main
int main() {
    readline();
    encrypt();
    decrypt();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Note** that `shiftdirection[strcspn(shiftdirection, "\n\r")] = 0;` checks the string for leftover `\n` so `getchar()` might be subtituted.

I hope this is what you are looking for

**Edit:** Your `while((strlen(pass)>4) || (strlen(pass)<4));` is basically `while(strlen(pass)!=4);` which means that `pass` should always be 4 characters long. Is that the case? or the user can also enter less than 4?

**Update:**

Checked the

`while ((strcmp(shiftdirection,left)==1) && strcmp(shiftdirection,right)==1))` condition again, cause it was wrong.

Change it to 
`while ((strcmp(shiftdirection,left)!=0) && (strcmp(shiftdirection,right)!=0))`.

When `strcmp(shiftdirection,left)` or `strcmp(shiftdirection,right)` are not `left` or `right` accordingly, the value is `-1` not `1`.

Comment: Also please enlighten me what the `key` variable does

Comment: I'm still having the same problem when getting the user input for enter direction:
If I enter "left" it encrypts and decrypts
If i enter "right" it re-asks for the direction again and does not encrypt nor decrypt. The key variable is shift bits number

Comment: I doesn't do that in my compiler. I just tested it again and works fine

Comment: @qwerty12345 write down on a comment your inputs and let me test it

Comment: @DA I added a screenshot

Comment: I don't why, I've tried on another compiler it works fine.

Comment: @qwerty12345 There might be somewhere a leftover `\0`. I tested your input and works perfectly.  Keep in mind to leave the `getchar()` after `scanf_s("%d",&key);` cause with digits capturing the `\0` is different. Try adding watches to your variables in your debugger and check the values, to see if every variable has the value it is supposed to have

Comment: also try to recompile the project, it might just be stuck

Comment: @qwerty12345 Last but not least, check the `while((strlen(pass)>4) || (strlen(pass)<4));` and consider what you want to check with this condition. Also add after `fgets(pass, sizeof pass, stdin);` this line: `pass[strcspn(pass, "\n\r")] = 0;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143795/discussion-between-d-a-and-qwerty12345).